# Наказовий спосіб дієслів для першої особи множини

Tags: дієслова, conjugation, наказовий-спосіб

Чи є коректним оминання кінцевого голосного у дієсловах наказового способу першої особи множини: "ходім подивимось" замість "ходім**о** подивимось"?

Стаття у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1) лише згадує про його існування для 1-ї особи у множині, але не містить прикладів.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Так, оминання кінцевого `o` є коректним, та вживається здебільшого в розмовній та в поетичній мові (задля збереження ритму, наприклад українська народна пісня [«Ой добраніч усім на ніч, **ходім**, любко, спати»](http://nashe.com.ua/song/10783)). Зверніть увагу, що для для 1-ї особи множини існує 2 типи закінчень:

> 1. -ім(о)/-їм(о) — *пишім(о), говорім(о), стоїм(о)*
> 2. -мо — *даймо, читаймо, сідаймо*

Кінцеве `o` може зникати лише в закінченнях першого типу, тобто коли перед `м` є `i`. Про те, які саме дієслова отримують закінчення типу 1, а які типу 2, можна [почитати тут](http://svitslova.com/mova/morpho/4140-2013-11-14-18-09-12.html).